# How to reproduce System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed result in Python

Tags: c#, .net, python, cryptography

Here's the deal: I'm moving a .NET website to Python. I have a database with passwords hashed using the System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed utility.

I'm creating the hash in .NET with the following code:

```
string hashedPassword = Cryptographer.CreateHash("MYHasher", userInfo.Password);
```

The MYHasher block looks like this:

```
<add algorithmType="System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=blahblahblah"
    saltEnabled="true" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithmProvider, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Security.Cryptography, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=daahblahdahdah"
    name="MYHasher" />
```

So for a given password, I get back and store in the database a 48 byte salted sha1. I assume the last 8 bytes are the salt. I have tried to reproduce the hashing process in python by doing a sha1(salt + password) and sha1(password + salt) but I'm having no luck.

My question to you:

1. How are the public keys being used?
2. How is the password rehashed using the salt.
3. How is the salt created? (e.g., When I say saltEnabled="true", what extra magic happens?)

I need specific details that don't just reference other .NET libraries, I'm looking for the actual operational logic that happens in the blackbox.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for the late reply, but I've just come across a similar situation while trying to replicate the SHA1 hashing logic used in the Enterprise Library's Cryptography Block, but with using Java.

To answer each of your questions:

1. **How are the public keys being used?**

   The PublicKeyToken in the configuration block above is used to identify a signed, strong-named .net  assembly. This is a 64-bit hash of the public key that corresponds to the private key used to sign the assembly. **NOTE: This key has absolutely no bearing on your implementation to hash data.**
2. **How is the password rehashed using the salt.**

   The sequence of events to create the hashed password with the salt is as follows:

   - Call `Cryptographer.CreateHash("MYHasher",value);`
     where `"MYHasher"` is the name of the configured `System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed` instance provider specified in your configuration block, and `value` is the string to be hashed.
   - The above method makes a call to `CreateHash(IHashProvider provider, string plaintext)`, where a resolved `IHashProvider` is supplied. Inside this method, the following code is run:

   ```
   byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plaintext);
   byte[] hash = provider.CreateHash(bytes);
   CryptographyUtility.GetRandomBytes(bytes);
   return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
   ```

   - The `value` argument that was passed right at the beginning (which is now the `plaintext` argument) is converted into a byte array, using Unicode encoding.
   - Next, the SHA1 hash provider's `CreateHash(bytes)` method is called with the byte array created above. Inside this method, the following steps occur:
   - `this.CreateHashWithSalt(plaintext, (byte[]) null);` is called, where `plaintext` is a byte array containing the original `value` passed in at the top of the stack as a string. The second argument is the salt byte array (which is null). Inside this method, the following code is called:

   ```
   this.AddSaltToPlainText(ref salt, ref plaintext);
   byte[] hash = this.HashCryptographer.ComputeHash(plaintext);
   this.AddSaltToHash(salt, ref hash);
   return hash;
   ```

   - `this.AddSaltToPlainText(ref salt, ref plaintext)` is the first clue as to how the supplied text is salted. Inside this method, the following code runs:

   ```
   if (!this.saltEnabled)
       return;
     if (salt == null)
       salt = CryptographyUtility.GetRandomBytes(16);
     plaintext = CryptographyUtility.CombineBytes(salt, plaintext);
   ```

   - The `this.saltEnabled` variable is initialised by the `saltEnabled="true"` in your configuration block. If true, and if you haven't supplied a salt, a byte array of 16 random bytes will be generated for you (via calling an external C API).
   - The `plaintext` variable then has the salt **prepended** to it. e.g.: [salt][plaintext]

**This is very important to note!**

- The combination of the salt and `plaintext` are then SHA1-hashed by calling `this.HashCryptographer.ComputeHash(plaintext);`. This will produce a 20 byte long array.
- Then, the salt is **prepended again** to the 20 byte array created previously, via the call `this.AddSaltToHash(salt, ref hash);`, to give you a 36 byte long array.
- Going back up the stack will eventually lead you to the call `return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);` inside the `CreateHash()` method. This will return the Base64 string representation of the SHA1 salted hashed value + salt that was supplied.

Formula: Base64(salt + SHA1(salt + value))

3. **How is the salt created? (e.g., When I say saltEnabled="true", what extra magic happens?)**

   This was answered in question 2, specifically the call to `CryptographyUtility.GetRandomBytes(16);` which eventually calls a C library:

`[DllImport("QCall", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern void GetBytes(SafeProvHandle hProv, byte[] randomBytes, int count);`

Hope this helps in some way!

Answer (score 1):

According to [this previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126148/what-is-the-salt-in-enterprise-library-hashprovider-saltenabled-key), this should be something like sha1(password+salt)+salt. SHA-1 output is twenty bytes, so for 48 bytes this should be a 28-byte salt, not an 8-byte salt, unless some sort of encoding was used.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `string CreateHash(string, string)` overload, the following occurs:

1. The string is converted to bytes using UTF16 (using Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes()).
2. A random 16-byte salt is generated.
3. The salt is appended to the converted string and hashed.
4. The salt is appended to the hash.
5. The hash+salt is converted back to a string using base64 (using Convert.ToBase64String()).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Gareth Stephenson! your answer had all the answers I needed. I was getting completely lost with this. I needed to upgrade a legacy module that was using this enterprise library, but there were so many problems with compiling I couldn't debug the code. Keeping the code opened a zillion other problems with dependencies and public key token mismatches / versions. 
So I re-wrote the functions needed based on Gareth's answer. I eventually found the encryption used in the config file. This can be in the app.config (in my case), web.config or other config somewhere:

```
<securityCryptographyConfiguration>
<hashProviders>
  <add algorithmType="System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
    saltEnabled="true" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithmProvider, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Security.Cryptography, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=06300324c959bce8"
    name="ABC" />
</hashProviders>
```

The code I wrote is:

```
//Because of the random salt added, each time you hash a password it will create a new result.
    public static string GetHashedValue(string password)
    {
        //this will create a new hash?
        //Hashed Password Formula: Base64(salt + Sha1(salt + value))
        var crypto = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] saltBytes = new byte[16];
        RandomNumberGenerator.Create().GetBytes(saltBytes); 

        byte[] checkPasswordBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password);
        byte[] tempResult = crypto.ComputeHash(saltBytes.Concat(checkPasswordBytes).ToArray()); //ComputeHash(salt + value)
        byte[] resultBytes = saltBytes.Concat(tempResult).ToArray();  //salt + ComputeHash(salt + value)

        return Convert.ToBase64String(resultBytes);
    }
```

and to check the validity of a password:

```
public static bool IsPasswordValid(string passwordToCheck, string savedPassword)
    {
        bool retVal = false;

        var crypto = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();

        //get the salt, which is part of the saved password. These are the first 16 bytes.
        byte[] storedPasswordBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(savedPassword);
        byte[] saltBytes = new byte[16];
        Array.Copy(storedPasswordBytes, saltBytes, 16);

        //hash the password that you want to check with the same salt and the same algoritm:
        byte[] checkPasswordBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(passwordToCheck);
        byte[] tempResult = crypto.ComputeHash(saltBytes.Concat(checkPasswordBytes).ToArray()); //ComputeHash(salt + value)
        byte[] resultBytes = saltBytes.Concat(tempResult).ToArray();  //salt + ComputeHash(salt + value)
        string resultString = Convert.ToBase64String(resultBytes);

        if (savedPassword == resultString)
        {
            retVal = true;
        }

        return retVal;
    }
```

And that just before I thought I would have to reset all my customers' passwords... I hope this will safe someone else as well one day!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Leo Muler , your csharp code helped me a lot to translate it into nodejs.

Here is the code :

```
   const saltLength = 16;
const cryptedPwd = 'm2gFufL1WYJEcjdgnu4Eo0qXHM8+whC75AMnYxCS+uRbiS4OBy5+4TKNQbiSJyTG';
const pwd = 'myPassword';

let binaryPwd = Buffer.from(cryptedPwd, 'base64');

let salt = binaryPwd.slice(0, saltLength);
let saltBuffer = [...salt];
let bytePwd = Buffer.from(pwd, 'utf16le');
let pwdBuffer = [...bytePwd];
let saltAndPwd = saltBuffer.concat(pwdBuffer);
let saltAndPwdBinary = Buffer.from(saltAndPwd).toString('utf16le');
let cryptedBuffer = Array.from(crypto.createHash('sha256').update(saltAndPwdBinary, 'utf16le').digest());
let concatCryptedBuffer = saltBuffer.concat(cryptedBuffer);
let cryptedString = Buffer.from(concatCryptedBuffer).toString('base64');

console.log('cryptedString : ' + cryptedString);
console.log('same : ' + (cryptedString == cryptedPwd));
console.log('');
```