# Compare salted hashed passwords in Python for authorisation

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, hash

In company we move some parts of the system from .NET to python. One of these parts is logging/authorization module. I need to implement in python [CryptographyManager.CompareHash Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ee776749(v%3Dpandp.10)). It takes salted and hashed password from database and compares it with user input (plaintext). To do it I have to salt and hash user input and then check it with hashed password from database.

The password in the database was hashed by Microsoft Enterprise `Library.Security.Cryptography`. Here more details:

> **Symmetric Crypto Providers:**
>   algorithmType="System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged name="AES"
>
> **Hash Providers**:
>   algorithmType="System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed
>   saltEnabled="true" name="SHA256"

I found that password is slated in that way: `Base64(salt + SHA256(salt + password))`. The salt is the first 16 bytes from the hashed password

What I am trying to do is get salt from hashed password in database and next hash and salt user input (plain text) to compare both.

Unfortunately, in the end there is no succes. Hashes are diffrent. Probably I am doning something wrong with de/encoding

My code looks like that:

```
import base64
import hashlib

hash = 'EwxBhfN0fM5Puv8/z+3/L50QvdU6BHFb4XQU9xtye/mOXJ8tBPc3tIyW7dEiZrvA'
password = 'some_plain_password' 

#password = password.encode()
password = base64.b64decode(password)

#hash to byte
b_hash = base64.b64decode (hash)
print(b_hash)

#get salt, first 16 bytes
salt = b_hash[:15]
salt=base64.b64encode(salt)
print(salt)

m = hashlib.sha256()
m.update(salt)
m.update(password)

print(m.hexdigest())
```

Comment: Thanks for submitting a new question. This one is much clearer than the last one. Should `'some_plain_password'` actually hash to the hash value you're showing here? Having a plaintext / hash pair would help us troubleshoot. At least part of the problem is likely `password = base64.b64decode(password)`—unless your client is sending a Base64-encoded password to your back-end there's no reason to be doing this. The code you're showing with `'some_plain_password'` makes it look like you already have the plaintext password. Similarly, I don't see why you'd do `salt=base64.b64encode(salt)`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit tricky to do this without an example plaintext and hash to verify the results, but your code should implement the algorithm you list in your question:

> `Base64(salt + SHA256(salt + password))`

I think you want something like this:

```py
import base64
import hashlib

hash = 'EwxBhfN0fM5Puv8/z+3/L50QvdU6BHFb4XQU9xtye/mOXJ8tBPc3tIyW7dEiZrvA'
salt = base64.b64decode(hash)[:16]  # Use 16 here, not 15

password = 'some_plain_password'

# First let's do the SHA256(salt + password) part
m = hashlib.sha256()
m.update(salt)
m.update(password.encode('utf-8'))

# Now let's feed that into the Base64 part
new_hash = base64.encode(salt + m.digest())
```

Comment: I'm not getting the right hash, but it looks close (the base64-encoded hash looks right, and the overall length looks right). Can you point me to the documentation where you learned about `Base64(salt + SHA256(salt + password))`?

Comment: To be honest I could not find any official source from Microsoft and after that I trusted what I found in stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495283/how-to-reproduce-system-security-cryptography-sha1managed-result-in-python/27247012#27247012)

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with pair plain password/hash. I will re-check it tomorrow in the office.

Answer (score 0):

My post is not 100% answer but more the end of the story.
The problem is that there is no official source how works CryptographyManager.Compare/Create Hash 
I tried a lot of combinations with Base64(salt + SHA256(salt + password)) but without succes.
Finally, I decide to rewrite C# code.
If someone is looking for python code that is salting and hashing password and compare two hashes, below is my working example:

```
import base64
import hashlib
import os


class Hashing(object):

    # base64( SHA256(password + salt) + salt)

    # generate new salt (default 16 bytes_
    def generate_new_salt(self, salt_ln=16):

        self.new_salt = os.urandom(salt_ln)

        print(f'new salt: {self.new_salt}')

        return self.new_salt

    # get salt from hash
    def get_old_salt(self, input_hash, salt_ln=16):

        self.old_salt = base64.b64decode(input_hash)[-salt_ln:]

        print(f'old salt: {self.old_salt}')

        return self.old_salt

    # compute hash using parameters
    def compute_hash(self, password, salt):

        self.salt = salt
        self.enc_password = password.encode()

        # hashing SHA256(password + salt)
        hash_object = hashlib.sha256(self.enc_password + salt)

        # add salt to hash and encode to base64
        hash_b64 = base64.b64encode(hash_object.digest() + salt)

        print(f'new_hash: {hash_b64}')
        return hash_b64

    # create hash from new or old salt
    def create_hash(self, password, salt_ln=16,old_salt=None):

        if old_salt:    #if old salt then use it
            self.salt = old_salt
        else:           #else generate new salt
            self.salt = Hashing().generate_new_salt(salt_ln)


        hash = Hashing().compute_hash(password, self.salt)

        return hash

    # compare input hash with created using salt get from input
    def compare_hashes(self, password, old_hash, salt_ln=16):

        self.enc_password = password.encode()

        #get salt from input hash
        self.old_salt = Hashing().get_old_salt(old_hash, salt_ln)

        #recreat input hash
        re_hash = Hashing().create_new_hash(password,salt_ln, self.old_salt)

        print(f'Compare: old_hash: {old_hash}')
        print(f'Compare: new_hash: {re_hash}')

        #compare
        if re_hash.decode() == old_hash.decode():
            return True
        else:
            return False


#code below is just for testing

NewSalt = Hashing().generate_new_salt()

Hash = Hashing().create_new_hash('pass')

OldSalt = Hashing().get_old_salt(Hash)

CompareHash = Hashing().compare_hashes('pass', Hash)

if CompareHash:
    print('HASHES THE SAME')
else:
    print('NOT THE SAME')

print(CompareHash)
```